# Decompose into a series of Coherent States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, coherent-states

I was wondering if there was a method for decomposing a given quantum state into a series of coherent states. I know they form an overcomplete basis so the expression need not be unique but I was wondering if there was an analytical or numerical method that could accomplish such a decomposition.

Comment: related to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/345543/36194

Answer (score 0):

The decomposition you're looking for is the [Glauber-Sudarshan P representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glauber%E2%80%93Sudarshan_P_representation).